# How to scroll screen to left (like -100%)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got this code connected to my divs on http://g7media.cz/svilla/

Scroll to right works great but i can't scroll to left content.

In this code i thought i scrolling screen trought html and body to left content just as i did on the other side.

```
var screen_position =0;

var height=$(window).height()-$('.header').height()-$('.footer').height()-95;

$('.content').css('max-height', height);

$('a.toright').on('click', function(event) {
    var screen_width=$(window).width();
    var divwidth = $('.backgroundright').width();

    if( screen_position == 0) { 
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: screen_width}, 800);
        screen_position=screen_width; 
        $('.backgroundright').animate({'right': screen_width-divwidth}, 800);
    }
    else {
        screen_position = screen_position-screen_width;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: screen_position}, 800);
        $('.backgroundright').animate({'right': 0}, 800);
    }



    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log(screen_position);
});

$('a.toleft').on('click', function(event) {
    var screen_width=$(window).width();
    var divwidth = $('.backgroundleft').width();

    if( screen_position == 0) { 
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: 0-screen_width}, 800);
        screen_position=screen_width; 
        $('.backgroundleft').animate({'left': 0-screen_width}, 800);
    }
    else {
        screen_position = screen_position-screen_width;
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: 0}, 800);
        $('.backgroundleft').animate({'left': 0}, 800);
    }



    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log(screen_position);
});
```

Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works. I've simply moved the position of the "slide to left" div so it's on the correct page and everything seems to be working fine. It was left: 0; and it's now left: 100%;

Updated CSS here:

```
.hometoleft {
    background: url("/svilla/img/homepagetoleft.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 407px;
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 124px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to show .backgroundleft content which has position left: -100%. For that i want to click to a.toleft and want to move my screen to the left.

Comment: Your code is working for that too. The CSS is the issue.
Just add "z-index: 1;" to your backgroundleft class in style.css (line 93).

The page is animating in, but is below every other layer, so was invisible!

However, there is still some work to do with your code as it is treating the "left" buttons as one entity and is toggling the left pane instead of scrolling back to the homepage.

Comment: I got this code wrong. I want to move screen just as i do with scroll to right page. The code I used moving the div "background" to right, but instead of it I want to move screen to this div(to left for screen-width).

So it should be something like this
$('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: 0-screen_width}, 800);
$('.backgroundleft').animate({'right': screen_width}, 800);